# How to disable/enable a product programatically in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1, webapi

I am trying to emulate the same behavior as when you use the admin panel to disable a product. I am trying to do something like this:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

But I still see it as enabled in the admin panel.

Thanks.

Comment: This code should work. What is the status when you look in the admin panel, the product details? Make sure the reindex mode is "on save" if you want to see the changes immediately

Comment: If I go to products > catalog it still says enabled. And If I try to [GET] /products/search/?searchCriteria... I still see it and the status is equal to 1.

Comment: You are sure this code gets executed? Can you debug the code? Maybe try to set another property like description to see if the product gets saved. Check the error logs. I once was unable to save a product because of an invalid field... (you can check that by trying to save a change in the admin panel)

Comment: Yes I am sure it gets executed. I can and have debugged it. No logs. And no, it does not work.

Comment: You mean you can't save the product in the admin panel?

Comment: I can save it in the admin panel and it works fine. However if I save it programmatically, as I wrote above, it is not getting saved. I also set the price using ...->setPrice(24) and it does not change it either. I have added an extra line above just to see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50868/discussion-between-echron-and-awavi).

Comment: Also, I am using a product I made which extends virtual product.

Comment: Reindex may fix the issue immediately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was that `$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);` gets a product for the default store. And if you want to disable it globally you need to pass

```
$this->productRepository->get(
    $sku,
    true/* edit mode */,
    0/* global store*/,
    true/* force reload*/
);
```

Comment: Please explain how to use this code to disable the product globally?

Comment: This code does!

Comment: thank you - it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with below code,

You can check core file code, **vendor/magento/module-catalog-sample-data/Model/Product.php**

```
class Product
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }
    public function saveproduct()
    {

        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this one is when you are creating a new product. I now know what the problem is. I am saving the product just within the scope of the current store. But globally it will still be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`

Declare a dependency on it by adding it to your `__construct function`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

Then you can update the status and save it back with the following code in your method

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```