# how to enable disabled products via query?

Tags: database, sql, query

Hi I want to enable all products I have in my **Magento 2 store**, is there any **query** to **enable all products** we have using a single sql query ?
Thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152263/how-to-disable-enable-a-product-programatically-in-magento2/152585 you can refer from this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below sql command useful for you

```
SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
    WHERE attribute_id = (
        SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
        WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
    ) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 1
```

Comment: will this query enable all disabled products ?

Comment: yes enable all products using above query